# Projection Matrix Help

Tags: self-study, matrix, projection

I'm having trouble understanding the following in a review textbook I'm using, particularly the long equality with inverses and transposes, and the subsequent conclusion regarding the rank and trace of Qx.
[image]!

Could someone please explain it, or direct me to a link or freely available document that explains what is going on step by step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to call the matrix $X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ ,$\:$  "$H$" (for "hat", since it's usually called the 'hat-matrix', because it puts the hat on $y$):      $\quad\hat{y}=Hy$.

Note that $H^2=H$ (expand it out, and cancel an adjacent pair of terms that is a matrix and its inverse).

Then $Q=I-H$  and $Q^2=(I-H)^2 = I^2 -HI - IH +H^2$. Using known results, simplify this down to $Q$.

Then note that in the page you copied, above the marked section it says "the rank of an idempotent matrix equals its trace (see below for a proof)"  -- so look after that point for a proof of that fact. So now we know that rank(Q)=trace(Q).

Now you would want to relate X and Q. (If you don't see what to do there, you can always fall back on something like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49889/why-does-the-rank-of-the-design-matrix-x-equal-the-rank-of-xx))